# how to use Regex in Jmeter - response body

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am using Jmeter and send http request that this is it's results:

```
<html><head></head><link rel='icon' href='data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo='><body>Sorry, this is temporarily unavailable. (103)</body></html>
```

I want to save the code, meaning the 103.

I used regular expression extractor, and set it:

apply to: Main sample and sub sample

field to check: body

the problem is that I didn't success to found out what to put in the regula expression field.

Can someone please advise what is the regular expression to get the number 103?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
Sorry,[^<>]*\(([0-9]+)\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sBs7Za/1)

**Details**

- `Sorry,` - a literal substring
- `[^<>]*` - any 0+ chars other than `<` and `>`
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `([0-9]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits
- `\)` - a `)` char.

Note that the template that you need to set is `$1$` (you can even see that notation requirement in your screenshot).